# Converting letters from uppercase to lowercase and the other way around

Tags: c, character, ascii, uppercase, lowercase

I am attempting to solve the following problem:

> Write a program that reads a character from the keyboard. The program
> will print:
>
> the uppercase version of the character if it is lowercase the
> lowercase version of the character if it is uppercase the ASCII code
> of the character otherwise Sample Input: a Sample Output: A

This is my solution:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    char upper[26] = {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z'};
    char lower[26] = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'};
    char c;
    scanf("%c", &c);
    for(int i=0; i <= 26; i++) {
        if(c==upper[i]) {
            printf("%c", lower[i]);
            break;
        } else if(c==lower[i]){
            printf("%c", upper[i]);
            break;
        } else if(i==26) { //not in the english alphabet
            printf("%d", c);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Are there any issues with my approach to the problem?

My university uses a platform with hidden tests, and my solution gives the wrong output for 2/15 tests and throws a runtime error for another one of the tests while the following code passes all of them:

```
#include <stdio.h>


int main()
{
    char a;
    
    scanf("%c",&a);

    if(a>='A'&&a<='Z')
    {
        printf("%c",a+32);
    }
    else if(a>='a'&&a<='z')
    {
        printf("%c",a-32);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("%d",a);
    }
}
```

Comment: You have an off by one error here: `for (int i = 0; i <= 26; i++)`. What is the index of the last element of `upper` and `lower`?

Comment: Certainly `printf("%d", c);` -> `printf("%c", c);`: you want to print the `char`, not the ASCII value.

Comment: [`tolower`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/tolower) and [`toupper`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/toupper)? Together with [`isupper`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/isupper) or [`islower`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/islower)?

Comment: @Jaberwocky The last index is 25, which corresponds to 'Z', respectively 'z'. The idea is that if the i gets to 26, then the character isn't in one of the arrays. I need to output the ascii value if the character is not a letter.

Comment: The `if (i == 26)` needs to be first, because `upper[i]` and `lower[i]` are not valid when `i` is 26. In fact, what you should do is write the loop as `for (i=0; i < 26; i++)`, and then put the `if (i == 26)` after the loop.

Comment: @AlexandruTodea but you're reading beyond the end of the array. Accessing `upper[26]` is wrong, it will result in undefined behaviour such as various runtime errors.

Comment: Bonus: the first version of the program even with the suggested corrections is very inefficient. Exercise for you: find out why.

Answer (score 0):

If the only objective is to turn a single char into the oposite case, then you can take into consideration the ASCII values:

The Upper case letters' range goes from `65`to `90`, and the lower case goes from `97` to `122`. This means that a char `c = 65` is the same as having `c = A`.

Having this into consideration, you can do something like this:

```c
if (c > 96 && c < 122)
    c -= 32;
else if (c > 64 && c < 91)
    c += 32;
```

This way, if the ASCII value represents a lower case Char, just subtract 32 (diference between 90 and 65).
But, if the ASCII value represents a Upper case Char, you do the opposite, and add 32.

If this makes it easier to understand, you can also do it like this:

```c
if (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z')
    c -= 32;
else if (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z')
    c += 32;
```

EDIT: You can consult the ASCII table [here](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII)